# Techniques to prevent overdraw (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm drawing lots of semi transparent polygons. My scene is 2D and uses 2f verticies. I can't use the depth buffer since it wont help because of alpha blending. What are some other techniques to reduce overdraw since this is what is crippling my application, not polygon counts since I use VBO's.

Comment: What do you mean by 'overdraw' exactly? Just because you're using VBO's doesn't mean you can't try and render too much at once.

Comment: @Jon Cage: Basically, drawing the same pixel many times while rendering the scene. Some overdraw is necessary when using semitransparent polys, but I'm pretty sure you could order your polys front-to-back and then use some stencil magic to not draw to pixels after you've already drawn them some number of times.

Comment: I mean, if I draw a 50x50 array of squares, it doesnt lag, but 50x50 squaes 1 on top of the other does a lot.

Comment: Is there a way it could figure out the end result pixel then put it once?

Comment: how accurate results do you want? If, say, you draw 50 polys on top of each others, must the transparency take them all into account, or can it get away with blending between, say, the topmost 5 polys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, how have you determined that overdraw is your problem?  Without more information about what exactly you are drawing, it is quite hard to guess how to draw it faster.  Speaking generally, the key to avoiding over draw is to avoid  drawing anything that isn't required.  So, if you have a 2D side scroller game with several layers of background image scrolling independently for parallax purposes -- sky, clouds, mountains, forest far, and forest near -- you would want to avoid drawing the sky wherever any of the other layers is visible.  So, if you know that the mountains are guaranteed to cover a certain part of the sky, change the shape of your sky poly to only draw in the areas where you expect the sky to be visible.  Potentially, make a fairly high resolution grid for the sky which follows the shape of the mountains, if you still have a problem.  Likewise, if the ground plane of the forest layers is guaranteed to cover a certain height span, then don't have the mountains being drawn in that area.

OTOH, on modern video hardware, a few layers of overdraw in a 2D scene is usually not that big of a deal, so I'm still interested to know exactly how you determined this, and if there might be some sort of bias in your instrumentation and profiling which could be leading you astray.

Comment: I'm making a vector drawing application, I'm pushing it and after about 35 layers it gets laggy, not on my pc, but on my laptop, I just wanna make it as fast as possible.

Comment: want me to upload the exe so you can evaluate yourself?

Comment: @user146780: Sure, it could help!

Answer (score 0):

In your specific scenario, I would consider rendering some batch of layers into an OpenGL FBO (the static ones).
Then compositing dynamic layers with static ones, etc.

After all if it's a vector drawing application, you don't need to redraw everything at each user interaction.

Comment: I have to redraw everything OnScroll()

Comment: Could you render a large patch once (and then copy a suitable proportion or the large patch) or does it all change really frequently?

Comment: @user146780: Does OnScroll() mean zooming in, zooming out? If you have to render everything at each time this event is triggered, this shouldn't be a problem: zooming in means less primitives to draw, zooming out means less pixels to blend.

Comment: No, it means GlTranslating everything by camera.x, camera.y as you might expect from a scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

If you're drawing a complex, multi-layer background that's causing jank, then you can try what I did.  Instead of drawing the multi-layers to the main canvas one at a time, I drew them to their own separate canvas (not to the screen), and then drew that finalized canvas to the screen.  It dropped my jank down by over a third.

```
private final Rect rect;
private final Bitmap bitmap;
private final Canvas canvas;

public Background()
{
    rect = new Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rect.width(), rect.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
}

public void draw(final Canvas g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        drawBackground(i);
    }
    g.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}

private void drawBackground(final int i)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(background[i], xPos[i], 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(background[i], xPos[i] + background[i].getWidth(), 0, null);
}
```